# R - Identifying only strings ending with A and B in a column

Tags: r, sample, replicate

I have a column in a data frame in R that contains sample names. Some names are identical except that they end in A or B at the end, and some samples repeat themselves, like this:

```
df <- data.frame(Samples = c("S_026A", "S_026B", "S_028A", "S_028B", "S_038A", "S_040_B", "S_026B", "S_38A"))
```

What I am trying to do is to isolate all sample names that have an A and B at the end and not include the sample names that only have either A or B.

The end result of what I'm looking for would look like this:
"S_026" and "S_028" as these are the only ones that have A and B at the end.

All I seem to find is how to remove duplicates, and removing duplicates would only give me "S_026B" and "S_38A" in this case.

Alternatively, I have tried to strip the A's and B's at the end and then sum how many times each of those names sum > 2, but again, this does not give me the desired results.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `substring` to get the last character after grouping by substring not including the last character, and check if there are both 'A', and 'B' in the substring

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(grp = substr(Samples, 1, nchar(Samples)-1)) %>% 
   filter(all(c("A", "B") %in% substring(Samples, nchar(Samples)))) %>% 
   ungroup %>% 
   select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 1
  Samples
  <chr>  
1 S_026A 
2 S_026B 
3 S_028A 
4 S_028B 
5 S_026B
```

Comment: Thank-you very much - you've just saved me many hours of work. However, I might add that S_026B is appearing twice. This is happening with my data too. To remedy this, I am using a `sort(unique(Samples))` at the end of the code to get just the ones that appear with both A's and B's at the end.

Comment: Is there a way, however, to only get the answers of S_026 and S_028 and not this list of just A's and B's?

Comment: @Purrsia Just remove the `select(-grp)` and use `%>% distinct(grp)`

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the last character from `Sample` in different column, keep only those values that have both `'A'` and `'B'` and keep only the unique values.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  extract(Samples, c('value', 'last'), '(.*)(.)') %>%
  group_by(value) %>%
  filter(all(c('A', 'B') %in% last)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  distinct(value)

#  value
#  <chr>
#1 S_026
#2 S_028
```